# Divide days into week day using Carbon excluding Saturday and Sunday

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have days in a month that excluded saturday and sunday. How to divide the range of the days into weeks? If it start with friday, then first week only friday.

Comment: It's going to be easier to help you if you share what code you currently have, otherwise solutions might have code that you won't be able to integrate in your own code

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $k = $i - 1;

    $from_text = strtotime("this week thursday -$i week");
    $to_text = strtotime("-$k week -1 day");

    $ymd_week_range = date('Y-m-d', $from_text) . ',' . date('Y-m-d', $to_text);

    $day_from = date('j', $from_text);
    $day_to = date('j', $to_text);

    $month_from = date('M', $from_text);
    $month_to = date('M', $to_text);

    $year_from = date('Y', $from_text);
    $year_to = date('Y', $to_text);

    $weeks[$ymd_week_range] = "$month_from $day_from - $month_to $day_to, $year_to";
}
```